# telethon forward Media (photos and videos)

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

I am using a telegram bot that forwards messages from a certain channel to any other channel I am on. I want it to forward media files, it doesn't forward media file.
Also getting this error:

> RPCError 400: CHAT_FORWARDS_RESTRICTED (caused by SendMediaRequest)

My code:

```
@BotzHubUser.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, chats=FROM))
async def sender_bH(event):
    for i in TO:
        try:
            await BotzHubUser.send_message(
                i,
                event.message
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: maybe this channel doesn't allow for this and you can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

As @furas pointed out in their comment, the channel probably has restricted content enabled, meaning you cannot reuse the media sent there.